# How to ensure that process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; is run first on npm run test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

What I try to achieve is that process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; should run first when I do npm run test. Here is what I did so far. 
**1. Added this to my package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./global-setup.js"
  }
```

**2. Created the file called as global-setup.js besides package.json and put the below code into that created file**

```
module.exports = async () => {
    process.env.TZ = 'UTC';
};
```

So, now when I do npm run test the following happens  **"test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:storyshots"**. What I tried is this: **"test:unit": "jest $npm_package_scripts_jest_globalSetup && jest --config ./jest.config.unit.js"**, why test:unit? since it runs first once I do npm run test. But no result((. I just to ensure that global-setup.js runs first with process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; inside of it to ensure that Jest's timezone is always UTC

Comment: Why the `async`? I feel like such a method should not be asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`npm#pre and post hooks`](https://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html).

Add this in the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:storyshots"",
    "pretest": "ENV TZ=UTC"
    "posttest": "add post things here"
  }
```

Comment: hi Riyaj thank you for your kind answer, but I got env: ‘TZ’: No such file or directory when I did npm run test

Comment: @MII my bad.Its space issue,Updates answer `"pretest": "ENV TZ=UTC"`use this one